# JXBrowser loads HTML, can't access Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, html, jxbrowser

I have see this issue pop up a bit, however I can't seem to remedy the problem. I am struggling to access my Javascript library after loading a local index.html file which uses this library. The error says 'cytoscape is not defined'.

I am using a LoadListener and am waiting until the frame is loaded with invokeAndWaitFinishLoadingMainFrame.

Code is below.

```
package src.java;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Callback;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.events.FinishLoadingEvent;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.events.LoadAdapter;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.swing.BrowserView;

public class VisualFrame {

public VisualFrame(final Browser browser, final BrowserView view, final JFrame frame){
    frame.setTitle("Visualisation");
    frame.setResizable(false);

    System.out.println(browser);

    browser.addScriptContextListener(new ScriptContextAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onScriptContextCreated(ScriptContextEvent event) {
              browser.executeJavaScript(event.getJSContext().getFrameId(),"window");
        }
    });  

    browser.addLoadListener(new LoadAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onFinishLoadingFrame(FinishLoadingEvent event) {
            if (event.isMainFrame()) {
                event.getBrowser().executeJavaScript("window");
            }
        }
    });

    InputStream urlStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("../web/cytoscape/index.html");
    String html = null;
    try (BufferedReader urlReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (urlStream))) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String row;
        while ((row = urlReader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(row);
        }
        html = builder.toString(); 
    }  catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    final String loadHelloPath = html;

    Browser.invokeAndWaitFinishLoadingMainFrame(browser, new Callback<Browser>(){
        @Override
        public void invoke(Browser arg0) {
            browser.loadHTML(loadHelloPath);
            System.out.println("HELLO");
        }
    });

    System.out.println(browser.getHTML());


}
}
```

When i call event.getBrowser().executeJavaScript("cytoscape.js") does the argument need to be something specific?

Also, does JxBrowser support all external JS libraries?

Thanks in advance.

Jack

Comment: the input param of executeJavaScript is javascript code, not the javascript file name

Comment: @yelliver in this case my Javascript code is long and within the code I have to access a JS library. I don't think writing out the whole library or my code to access it is the right method. Is there a way to link a file instead of the javascript code?

Comment: @yelliver i did notice this issue so I changed the input param to 'window'

Comment: @JackOnslow what happens now when you replace the incorrect "cytoscape.js" JS code with just "window"? I believe your example shouldn't print any JS errors anymore. The parameter you pass to the executeJavaScript() method represents JavaScript expression you would like to evaluate.

Comment: @JackOnslow Please check the documentation that shows how to use this method to invoke JavaScript from Java: https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013059-calling-javascript-from-java